# Need help in SLDS

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, slds, aura-attribute, slds-grid

`enter code here`[image]

Need to create design like this in screenshot. I am ready with the component but not sure what SLDS i can use to :

1) Showing Green Border top of each section
2) Display fields in 2 rows having 4 coloumns each.

Kindly suggest.  I have added my component.

```
<aura:component  implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >

  <aura:attribute name="Contact" type="Contact" default="{'sobjectType': 'Contact' }"/>
   <aura:attribute name="Contact1" type="Contact" default="{'sobjectType': 'Contact' }"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Contac2" type="Contact" default="{'sobjectType': 'Contact' }"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Contact3" type="Contact" default="{'sobjectType': 'Contact' }"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isDataSubmitted" type="boolean" default="false"></aura:attribute>

        <div class="slds-form--stacked slds-p-around--medium slds-m-bottom--x-small">
          <div class="slds-form-element">

             <div class="slds-border_top"> 
                            <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                                 <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1">
                      <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
                            <H1>Contact1#</H1>
                          <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid--pull-padded">
                          <div class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-4">
                              <div class="slds-size--1-of-4">
                                <lightning:input type="Contact" label="First Name" value="{!v.Contact.FirstName}" />
                                <lightning:input type="Contact" label="Last Name" value="{!v.Contact.LastName}" /> <br/>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>


                       <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-large" size="2" smallDeviceSize="12" mediumDeviceSize="2">
                     <lightning:input type="Contact" label="Email" value="{!v.Contact.Email}" />
                          </lightning:layoutItem>
                     <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-large" size="2" smallDeviceSize="12" mediumDeviceSize="2">
                     <lightning:input type="Contact" label="Department" value="{!v.Contact.Department}" />
                          </lightning:layoutItem>
                      <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-large" size="2" smallDeviceSize="12" mediumDeviceSize="2">
                     <lightning:input type="Contact" label="Level" value="{!v.Contact.Level__c}" />
                          </lightning:layoutItem>
                      <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-large" size="2" smallDeviceSize="12" mediumDeviceSize="2">
                     <lightning:input type="Contact" label="AssistantName" value="{!v.Contact.AssistantName}" />
                          </lightning:layoutItem>
                       <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-large" size="2" smallDeviceSize="12" mediumDeviceSize="2">
                     <lightning:input type="Contact" label="LeadSource" value="{!v.Contact.LeadSource}" />
                          </lightning:layoutItem>
                          </lightning:layout>
                                      </div>
                                          </div>
                                                  </div>



                       <div class="slds-border_top">   
                      <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
                            <H1>Contact2#</H1>

                            <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-large" size="12" smallDeviceSize="12" mediumDeviceSize="2">
                                <lightning:input type="Contact" label="First Name" value="{!v.Contact2.FirstName}" />
                         </lightning:layoutItem>


                          <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-large" size="2" smallDeviceSize="12" mediumDeviceSize="2">
                     <lightning:input type="Contact" label="Last Name" value="{!v.Contact2.LastName}" />
                          </lightning:layoutItem>
                       <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-large" size="2" smallDeviceSize="12" mediumDeviceSize="2">
                     <lightning:input type="Contact" label="Email" value="{!v.Contact2.Email}" />
                          </lightning:layoutItem>
                     <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-large" size="2" smallDeviceSize="12" mediumDeviceSize="2">
                     <lightning:input type="Contact" label="Department" value="{!v.Contact2.Department}" />
                          </lightning:layoutItem>
                          </lightning:layout>
                            </div>




                       <div class="slds-border_top">   
                      <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
                            <H1>Contact3#</H1>

                            <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-large" size="12" smallDeviceSize="12" mediumDeviceSize="2">
                                <lightning:input type="Contact" label="First Name" value="{!v.Contact3.FirstName}" />
                         </lightning:layoutItem>
                      <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-large" size="2" smallDeviceSize="12" mediumDeviceSize="2">
                     <lightning:input type="Contact" label="Last Name" value="{!v.Contact3.LastName}" />
                          </lightning:layoutItem>
                       <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-large" size="2" smallDeviceSize="12" mediumDeviceSize="2">
                     <lightning:input type="Contact" label="Email" value="{!v.Contact3.Email}" />
                          </lightning:layoutItem>
                     <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-large" size="2" smallDeviceSize="12" mediumDeviceSize="2">
                     <lightning:input type="Contact" label="Department" value="{!v.Contact3.Department}" />
                          </lightning:layoutItem>
                          </lightning:layout>
                            </div>




                       <div class="slds-border_top">   
                      <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
                            <H1>Contact4#</H1>

                            <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-large" 
             size="12" smallDeviceSize="12" mediumDeviceSize="2">
                                <lightning:input type="Contact" label="First 
               Name" value="{!v.Contact4.FirstName}" />
                         </lightning:layoutItem>


                          <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-large" size="2" 
                  smallDeviceSize="12" mediumDeviceSize="2">
                     <lightning:input type="Contact" label="Last Name" value=" 
              {!v.Contact4.LastName}" />
                          </lightning:layoutItem>
                       <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-large" size="2" 
               smallDeviceSize="12" mediumDeviceSize="2">
                     <lightning:input type="Contact" label="Email" value=" 
                 {!v.Contact4.Email}" />
                          </lightning:layoutItem>
                     <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-large" size="2" 
                 smallDeviceSize="12" mediumDeviceSize="2">
                     <lightning:input type="Contact" label="Department" value=" 
                 {!v.Contact4.Department}" />
                          </lightning:layoutItem>
                          </lightning:layout>
                            </div>

              <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
                         <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-large" size="2" 
                 smallDeviceSize="12" mediumDeviceSize="2">
                      <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Save All" 
                 title="Save All"  />  
                          </lightning:layoutItem>
                          </lightning:layout>
                </div>
      </div>
 </aura:component>
```

Comment: Please [edit] this post to show the community *what you've tried* and *where you're stuck*. See [ask].

Comment: @David  I have added component i have created. I am not getting how can i display the inputfields in this format. like 2 rows and 4 coloumns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is in your `lightning-layout-item`(LWC) | `lightning:layoutItem` (Aura) `size` property. you have them all set to 12 which is the max. You will need to set them all to 3 to achieve 4 columns. You will also need to reduce your padding as well as this only takes up more space than is needed using the `around-large`.

```
<lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" // small padding will add about 1rem around roughly
                      size="3"               // normal device, 1 column 3 columns remaining
                      smallDeviceSize="12">  // small device, 1 column full width (mobile)
   <lightning:input type="Contact" label="First Name" value="{!v.Contact2.FirstName}" />
</lightning:layoutItem>
```

as you adjust you may want to scale up or down the padding. or you can add a class attribute instead and use that for your  `lightning-input` (LWC) | `lightning:input` (Aura)

```
<lightning:layoutItem size="3"               // normal device, 1 column 3 columns remaining
                      smallDeviceSize="12">  // small device, 1 column full width (mobile)
   <lightning:input type="Contact" 
                    label="First Name"
                    class="slds-m-around-x_small"   // use margin arouund your component instead
                    value="{!v.Contact2.FirstName}" />
</lightning:layoutItem>
```

Comment: thanks it worked fine :)